# How can I add textbox/textfield in my swagger page built in Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am trying to auto-generate the swagger page for a RestAPI in Spring Boot using annotations.

**Code of Controller:**

```
@RestController
@Api(value="UserManagementAPI", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class UserManagementController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

    @ApiOperation(value="add a pro",consumes="application/json")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getUser", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")    
    public static List<UserDetails> getUser(@PathVariable(name="id") String id) throws UserException
    {
        return UserHelper.getUserByEmail(id);
    }
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "userManagement"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
@Bean
    public Docket simpleDiffServiceApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).groupName("userManagement").apiInfo(apiInfo()).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                // .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                // Will also include the basic error controllers by default
                .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error")))
                // Exclude basic error controllers
                .build().pathMapping("/");
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("Business Location Service")
                .description("Spring Boot REST APIs for Business Location Service")
                .contact(new Contact("EntSol-IoT (Niche Technology Delivery Group)", "http://somewebsite.com",
                        "some@mail.com"))
                .version("1.0").build();
    }
```

In the swagger page, I can see all my APIs. But there are more. It is showing all possible method type (e.g POST, GET, PUT etc.) though in Controller I only wrote GET method.
Another issue is that there is no Textbox in the swagger page under the API where I can search for the **id**. May be I am missing something. I have been trying to resolve it for past two days. But couldn't help myself. Thanks in advance.

[image: Swagger Page]

Comment: Can you help us by posting the swagger screen image and the Swagger version that you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the problem. Your `getUser` method is declared as `static`. Please remove `static`, for it to work.

`public List<UserDetails> getUser(@PathVariable(name="id") String id) throws UserException { }`

Comment: Do you have any idea why there are so many APIs apart from ours?

Comment: Because of 
`@RequestMapping("/")`
does not have method specified in `@RequestMapping`.
Try updating it to `@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)` for `index` method.

Comment: Yes! Perfect Now.. Thank you!